# libLAS georeference las file and update header

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, lidar, las, liblas

I am just starting to use libLAS and I had a small issue.

I have next code to generate a las file with georeferenced points:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
liblas::Header header;
liblas::SpatialReference srs;
srs.SetFromUserInput("EPSG:4326");
header.SetSRS(srs);
header.SetPointRecordsCount(1);
ofs.open("H:\\temp\\test2.las", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
liblas::Writer writer(ofs, header);

liblas::Point point(&header);
point.SetCoordinates(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
writer.WritePoint(point);

point.SetCoordinates(5, 5, 5);
writer.WritePoint(point);

point.SetCoordinates(-1, -1, -1);
writer.WritePoint(point);

header.SetPointRecordsCount(3);

writer.SetHeader(header);

writer.WriteHeader();
ofs.Close();
```

When I run lasinfo over this file I get: It says that I have 3 points, but my spatial reference is none.

[image]

Same code above, but if I comment this line:

```
//writer.SetHeader(header);
```

I can see the spatial reference, but the number of points is 1.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In your second scenario (the one without the rewriting of the header), do you keep `header.SetPointRecordsCount(1);` on line 6 of your code? What happens when you change that to `header.SetPointRecordsCount(3);` and remove the `SetPointRecordsCount()` from later (after you finish writing the points)?

Answer (score 4):

Once you open your writer, you don't need to modify your header at all. The header is written [when you create your writer](https://github.com/libLAS/libLAS/blob/master/src/writer.cpp#L67). Change your first call to `header.SetPointRecordsCount()` to the correct number of points (3) and remove your later calls to `header.SetPointRecordsCount()`, `writer.SetHeader()`, and `writer.WriteHeader()`.

Here's your original code, modified to work as you'd expect (at least on my system):

```
std::ofstream ofs;
liblas::Header header;
liblas::SpatialReference srs;
srs.SetFromUserInput("EPSG:4326");
header.SetSRS(srs);
header.SetPointRecordsCount(3);
ofs.open("H:\\temp\\test2.las", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
liblas::Writer writer(ofs, header);

liblas::Point point(&header);
point.SetCoordinates(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
writer.WritePoint(point);

point.SetCoordinates(5, 5, 5);
writer.WritePoint(point);

point.SetCoordinates(-1, -1, -1);
writer.WritePoint(point);

ofs.close();
```